# Add Fields to View page

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that is a page and I'd like to be able to add a a field to this page.

My other pages are content type pages and they have the option to assign a top hero banner content type to them. How can I assign a hero banner content type to a view page?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your view's edit screen do the following:

1.) Under Format, **Change Show: Content** to **Show: Fields**

- By clicking on Content and then selecting Fields

2.) Under Filter Criteria add **Type** and then check mark your content type name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an header field in your view.
[image: You can add an Header text field, in a Global Text format]